# ng test Process completed with exit code 1 on Github Action

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, angular-test

In my Angular project I want to run automated test on every push on any branches with this YAML file:

```yaml
on: [push]

jobs:
  ng-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: npm ci
      run: |
        cd angular/
        npm ci
    - name: ng test
      run: |
        cd angular/
        npm run test:ci
```

And the result is this:

```
Chrome Headless 96.0.4664.45 (Linux x86_64): Executed 18 of 23 (skipped 5) SUCCESS (0.817 secs / 0.519 secs)
TOTAL: 36 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 36 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 36 SUCCESS

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 32.12% ( 387/1205 )
Branches     : 11.75% ( 53/451 )
Functions    : 14.2% ( 45/317 )
Lines        : 29.78% ( 341/1145 )
================================================================================

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 32.12% ( 387/1205 )
Branches     : 11.75% ( 53/451 )
Functions    : 14.2% ( 45/317 )
Lines        : 29.78% ( 341/1145 )
================================================================================
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myproject@11.0.0 test:ci: `ng test --watch=false --code-coverage --source-map true`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@11.0.0 test:ci script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-12-06T12_08_18_494Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

In my local machine everything is fine.

What's wrong here? Any idea?